# Rendering the Next Component if all the validations are correct with React.JS Link Tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a button on click of which i go to the next page , i.e

```
<Link to="/results"><button>Calculate</button></Link>
```

But i want to go the next page , only if few validations or a flag showResults is true . And, i dont want to hide the button also . Button should be there , but it should go to the next page only if the validations are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to update the path of your link.

You could do something like this:

```
render(){
    const toLink = condition ? '/' : '/results'
    return(
        <Link to={toLink}><button>Calculate</button></Link>
    )

}
```

Comment: The path should be same, but it should to the next link only if the flag showResults is true . And, i also don't want to hide the button till then. The button should be visible , but it should take to next page if the flag value is true.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your comment but in my example the button is alway visible. It is only the "to link" that changes. Are you saying the link should always be the same but you just want the link button disabled if the condition isn't set?

Answer (score 0):

You can add preventDefault()

```
render(){
    return(
        <Link to={toLink} onClick={(e) => {if (!showResults) {e.preventDefault();}}}>
            <button>Calculate</button>
        </Link>
    )

}
```